# How can we set width and height of flex application by using javascript?

Tags: flex3

I developed one flex application to which we want to set the flex application width and height by using javascript. Or is there any other way? please find the soloution.

thanks,
harikrishna.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way

1st embed your application using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

when you want to change the dimensions simply embed it again with the new dimensions.
[SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) has great documentation and a well thought out [JS API](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api).

The 2nd thing you will have to do is pass the width and the height to the flex application and set the height and the width simply by

```
application.width = x;
application.height = y;
```

Comment: I referred you to the documentation.